# How to confirm mysql database backup using mysqldump in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $backupfile = 'bkp_dbcreditors_' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.sql';

    $command = "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqldump -u root -pare048 dbcreditors >   $backupfile";

    system($command);
    echo "Backup taken.";

    exit();
    ?>
```

Is there a way to confirm that backup is not taken, if such happens?

Answer (score 1):

Read the return value of the system($command). http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

It returns false on failure.

Comment: could you please add code how to read the return value of system()?

Comment: if (system($command)!=FALSE) {
echo "Backup taken in file ". $backupfile;
} else{
echo "Backup failed";
}
exit();
but it does not work

Comment: I finally figured it out: if (!system($command, $return)) {
 echo "Backup taken in file ". $backupfile;
} else{
 echo "Backup failed";
}